# Audio assistant that works without the Internet

Tags: audio, assistive-technology

[This question](https://www.reddit.com/r/alexa/comments/7m6428/what_can_an_echo_do_without_internet_access/) on Reddit describes my situation better than I could:

> [...] Voice recognition? Cool [...] But I'm a huge internet privacy advocate, all my stuff is self-hosted, secure out the ass, and has as little reliance on large corporations as technologically possible.

In other words, I am looking for a voice assistant that works without connecting to the internet; everything they would need is available in a local network: Telephony/SIP Server, SMB/AFP/NFS/Bonjour/UPnP/LDAP/vCard server... - some of these services are provided by a Synology NAS, some by an internet router with additional features built in.

Recently Google announced that their Pixel [speech recognition can work offline](https://techcrunch.com/2019/03/12/googles-new-voice-recognition-system-works-instantly-and-offline-if-you-have-a-pixel/).

I wouldn't be too scared to do complicated configuration or even add some services to my local network servers to allow a voice assistant to work, though my spare time is limited.

The ideal voice assistant could read data from my local network address book, initiate phone calls, work as IP telephony device, plays music and allows me using it as Bluetooth speaker and may switch some wall sockets on and off. Ideally it would also support working as a pulseaudio sink. Maybe it could fetch some information from Wikipedia and read out loudly, too.

Amazon announced their Echo Studio and the hardware looks very promising, given its price. However, as I understand it is entirely useless without being connected to the internet.

Comment: You should post this question on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/), unless you are looking specifically for a "smart speaker" *device* that has a self-hosted assistant. This question seems off-topic for this stack exchange site.

Comment: @Romen A self-hosted all-in-one device would be the easiest solution to the issue.

Comment: Since I last saw [Mycroft](https://mycroft.ai/), they have begun developing some [hardware](https://mycroft.ai/product/reserve-your-mark-ii-with-a-small-deposit/), although that device isn't available yet. You can run Mycroft on your own PC and use a regular speaker/microphone setup though.